# Rename [google-openid] to [google-account] here

Tags: discussion, meta, retag-request

The tag [google-openid](/questions/tagged/google-openid) has to do with logging into SE with a Google account.

However, said login path no longer uses OpenID since it's now deprecated.

The tag is still relevant for questions about signing in through Google accounts via the new path, though, and a question about it just cropped up.

Can we please rename the tag to something like [google-account](/questions/tagged/google-account)?

Comment: That makes 72 questions that need to be edited then. Is it so bad to tag future questions `google account` Why do old tags have to be deleted?

Comment: @Mari-LouA An SE employee can merge the tag into the yet-to-exist [tag:google-account] tag, effectively renaming it without bumping any posts.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, why do old tags have to be deleted? If they were used correctly and appropriately, what's wrong with keeping them and just tagging future Qs with an updated tag?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ah, sorry, the system doesn't automatically load edited comments; I only saw your initial revision that contained only one sentence. Yeah, we could synonymize, which will keep the tags separate but redirect newer uses of the old tag to the new one. However, according to the FAQ, all synonyms should eventually be merged; I'm just proposing doing that as the first step. (If you want to just synonymize without merging, post that alternative suggestion as an answer.)